# How to secure a linux system

Tags: linux, security

-6

down vote

favorite

I`m n3w to this how and  what are the best tried and true ways to harden a linux system? say for example a fresh build of Ubuntu 14.10 I have been looking at seliunx vs apparmor and the only real difference I can see is on the forensics side of it. what are some good suggestions from Linux users to harden the surface of a stock built Ubuntu LTS? Also what are some good ideas for apps or programs that might assist with that thank you for your time.

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/1075718/105002

Comment: I'm going to say that you shouldn't have copied the -6 votes from the prior version of the question.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.10 is also end-of-life.  Ubuntu 14.04.x LTS should be good until 2019.  And there is a new LTS too that just came out: 16.04 LTS.  Non-LTS versions have much shorter lives.  If you want good security then skip Ubuntu and go with Arch as you will only install with it exactly what you want which means a smaller surface area to attack.  See: [The Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Security) for how to harden a system.

Comment: @Frank but it's the best laugh I've had today..

Comment: The previous time you asked this [question](http://superuser.com/questions/1075718/how-do-you-harden-linux), it wasn't on topic, it still isn't on topic.  Instead of opening a third question, which will be closed, improve one of your existing questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are a lot of guides to follow to secure a brand new linux system. The short answer is to follow best practices, keep things updated, use good passwords, turn off processes that you are not using. Make sure you are running the latest version of your OS, currently it's 16.04 LTS for Ubuntu.

It's hard to point to a single guide, because it matters how you are going to use the machine. You would do different things if you are setting up a webserver vs an email server.

With selinux vs apparmor, I'd say use apparmor, because, in my opinion, AppArmor is better supported in Ubuntu land.